# Delete ACF repeater`s sub_field after expired date

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

i have repeater (‘pasirinkti_datas’), and in this repeater are stored datepicker (‘keliones_datos’) Y-m-d format.

I need to do a function that deletes repeater row if datepicker date is lower than todays date

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Agree with the Community Bot here, need more context of how the function is executed. Is this in the post admin, does this function run as soon as you change/update the `keliones_datos` date field in the post admin using acf javascript handlers or does this happen when the post is updated? Some code or context of how you need this to run would be helpful.

Comment: what have you tried so far? I would suggest you connect a js file to your acf field https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-custom-javascript-fields/ from there its a simple JS function to check the dates and remove the desired rows. There is a lot of documentation on the Javascript API here https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-custom-javascript-fields/